# PopoverController - deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

when I click the popover button in my splitviewcontroller, I receive the message: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a66ca0

I already found out that this instance has to be the detailviewcontroller I allocate and init. So far so good. But I don't see the problem while the whole thing is not working.

First of all the AppDelegate where I create the Splitview:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // TestViews for SplitViewController 
    // TestView1 *test1 = [[TestView1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestView1" bundle:nil];

    // TableView as RootViewController for the Left Hand Pane
    RootViewTableViewController *rootViewTableViewController = [[RootViewTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewTableView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewTableViewController];

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNavigationController,detailNavigationController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

First I was thinking the code line self.splitviewcontroller.delegate = detailviewcontroller; could be the problem..... but the whole app starts up perfectly. only when i click the button this prob appears.

the RootViewController is this ( I omitted the standard tableview delegate methods for clarity)

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // Set Title of the TableView for the RootViewController
        self.title = @"Notarzteinsatzprotokoll";
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    NSLog(@"INIT %p", self);
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

and the detail view controller:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Managing the Detail Item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.rootPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.rootPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setTitle:@"Notarzteinsatzprotokoll"];
    [self configureView];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Rotation Support

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SplitView

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
    barButtonItem.title = @"Master";
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.rootPopoverController = pc;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.rootPopoverController = nil;
}
```

I don't see the point the program flow where the detailviewcontroller objects is released and something else tries to send a message... do I have to interchange some code lines?

Thank you!
Sebastian

```
@end
```

Comment: I suggest putting break points at each relevant line of code and try to determine the exact part of your code that causes the error message. Then when you found that area step through the lines and find the exact source of your problem. I'm sure you will end up at the right object of your problems. Deal with it appropriately. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

the error should tell you what message is being sent to a deallocated instance. Not sure exactly what the issue is, is it a setTitle: message being sent to the left bar button item?

In splitViewController:willShowViewController: you set the left bar button item to nil (which will dealloc it) and in splitViewController:willHideViewController: you attempt to changed its title, which could be your problem.

Comment: Hm... I don't think it could be the splitView delegate message... Because they are only called one after another depending on the rotation of the device. and therefore I have to set it to nil or build one.